# Is my logic about proving an immersion correct?

Tags: proof-verification, differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Need to show that an injective map between manifolds need not be an immersion. $x^3$ example was given here but wanted to check if my justification suffices.
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/15317/is-an-injective-smooth-map-an-immersion

$f:R\rightarrow R$ ; $f(x)=x^3$. $f$ is an immersion iff $\forall x\in R$, $df_x$ is an injective linear transformation and for $x^3$, $df_0$ is a $zero$ transformation and hence not an injective linear transformation. Thus not an immersion? Thanks!

Comment: $df = 2x^2$ is not injective. It is a global property that checks all values, you can't just take a value because it will always be a constant.

Comment: I see, so I should look at the derivative as a function and see if it is injective? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, but how else would you check injectivity on non-functions?

Comment: True but by wiki definition $df_p$ needs to be injective at every $p\in M$, so I don't understand what they mean by being injective at every point $p$.

Comment: Can you link it to me?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immersion_(mathematics)  Thanks for checking.

Comment: That's exactly what I wrote, I just left out the point in my notation. What is the main confusion?

Comment: Do you know the definition of $df_x$?

Comment: Derivative of $f$ at $x$?

Comment: Yes, but what is your confusion? Do you know the definition of injectivity?

Comment: one-one, I understand how a function is injective (like $x^2$ is not) but don't understand what they mean by being injective at every $x$, does that just mean $df$ needs to be one-one $\forall x$?

Comment: You might be thinking about local injectivity. The circle is probably one of the example comes to mind.

Comment: But really just check whether $x \to df_x$ is injective for all $x \in M$ or not.

Comment: I see, the last comment clarifies it. Thanks.